# Who is the programmer behind SatoshiDice?

Tags: development, gambling, satoshidice

I have talked with Erik Voorhees and I learned that he is not the person that programmed SatoshiDice. Does anyone know who is the developer behind this game is?

Answer (score 7):

This is all I could dig up from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/SatoshiDice

> SatoshiDice was the brand given the service initially created by BitcoinTalk forum user FireDuck before selling the system to another operator.